# Determine sewer tap elevations along a sewer line shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a sewer collection line shapefile with upstream and downstream invert elevations (Up_el and Dwn_el). I have created a point shapefile of service connections based upon the endpoints of a private lateral line shapefile, using the data management tool "feature vertice to point" (I used endpoint).

I suppose that I could split each sewer line at the service connection point (sometimes called a "tap") and calculate the y value using the individual line slope and the distance the tap is down from the upstream manhole, but I am hoping there is a more eloquent tool or code to populate a tap elevation field for this point shapefile attribute table.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255469/route-events-wont-interpolate-z-values-on-3d-route/255481#255481